# How to Pass Multiple parameter to .vbs file from Java

Tags: java, excel, vbscript, vba

I have a VB Script (myVB2.vbs) written, which basically runs the macro in excel and saves the excel.
Here is my VB script(myVB2.vbs)

```
Dim objExcel, objWorkbook, filePath 

Set filePath = Wscript.Arguments(0)
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 'Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Writter\Excel.xlsm")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(filePath)
objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.Run "ChartUpdate"
objWorkbook.Save
objExcel.Quit

Set objWorkbook = Nothing
Set objExcel = Nothing

WScript.Quit
```

Now I will need to trigger this .vbs file from Java by passing argument of the excel file path to VBscript. With below piece of Java code, I am not able to Pass argument of the file path.I get error - **There is no script engine for file extension ".xlsm"**.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String scriptpath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\com\\domain\\function\\resources\\myVB2.vbs";
    String destinationlocation ="C:\\Writter\\Excel.xlsm" ;

        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
           try {
               Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "wscript"+ scriptpath+" "+destinationlocation);
           }
           catch( IOException e ) {
              e.printStackTrace();
           }

    }
```

Comment: Looks like you might want a space inside the `String` possibly? Try `Runtime.getRuntimee().exec("wscript " + scriptpath + " " + destinationlocation);`

Comment: Thanks Orin, You were right. And also the other reason was  I had give set for filepath. Once i removed set for filepath, it worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ProcessBuilder` instead of `.exec`:

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("wscript", scriptpath, destinationlocation).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank You all for your respone, My issue is resolved my adding " " in the wscript and also removing set from filepath in myVB2.vbs